# Swift 3 conversion Error/NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, swift-protocols, nserror

While trying to migrate to Swift 3 (in a project which contains about half/half swift/objective-c code), I am facing an issue. We declare this specific protocol in objective-c like this:

```
@protocol AProtocolDeclaration <NSObject>

- (void)someEventHappened:(nullable NSError *)error;

@end
```

Swift compiler generates the following for the protocol declaration above:

```
public protocol AProtocolDeclaration : NSObjectProtocol {

    public func someEventHappened(_ error: Error?)
}
```

And when implementing the protocol in a `concrete class (in swift)` and trying to define the generated method, I am keep on getting error something like : cannot convert `Error to NSError`. I'm not sure how to fix this error. Could any one please suggest?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md)

Comment: Please be more specific. Is your error "cannot convert Error to NSError" a runtime error or compile time error? Of course the code causing the issue is needed. And do not refer "something like" thing. Copy the exact error message on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a bug with SourceKit in Xcode 8.  As of Xcode 8.1 and 8.2 beta 2, protocols functions contain `NSError` parameters are bridged correctly to Swift 3 as `Error`:

```
extension MyClass: AProtocolDeclaration {
    func someEventHappened(_ error: Error?) {
        print(error ?? "none")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this surely was a bug in XCode and with new XCode, it's working fine.